# Adding Gallery to Footer of Homepage

Tags: plugins, gallery, footer

I wanted to add gallery with Thickbox effect(Pop up), i achieved this easily on the posts page by using WordPress gallery and the lightbox plugin.But the theme is custom made there is a footer.php.I don't know how to add this gallery to the footer pro grammatically please help

EDIT:Code on Posts Page

```
<a href="http://mysite.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/image.png">[gallery]
```

Comment: What did you do on the posts page? Can you edit your question to include the code?

Comment: @ChipBennett Plz  see edit

Comment: By "code on posts page", I assume you mean *code entered into the Post Editor*?

Comment: @ChipBennett I went to the posts page and and from the inserted the gallery from the visual editor and the code is obtained from the html version of the editor(html tab)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the gallery is rendered via a `[gallery]` shortcode, you can try using [**`do_shortcode()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode) in `footer.php`. For example, assuming you want to output a gallery with an ID of 1:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode( '[gallery id="1"]' ); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks tried it but all i got was echo do_shortcode( '[gallery id="1"]' ); printed on the Homepage

Comment: It's PHP code, and thus needs to be wrapped in `<?php` / `?>` tags.

Comment: Added it.Now nothing is printed but the gallery is not shown

Comment: What are you using for `$id`? Are you sure a gallery with that ID exists?

Comment: I do not know what is the id of the gallery.How can i find the id of the gallery

Comment: *"How can i find the id of the gallery?"* - Use the ID of the post to which the gallery is attached.

Comment: Thank you very much Now it worked.But the gallery images seems to have much spacing between them.Let me tell you why im doing this,the designer had created a gallery with the Roaster plugin,it looked perfect but the problem was,when clicking on images it lead to inner pages rather than opening  up a thickbox.Is there a way to open the roaster image gallery as thickboxes?

Comment: That's a separate question, and starts to border on being off-topic.

Comment: Thanks for your Help anyway.Im posting it as a separate quesyion

Comment: Is there a way to adjust the distance between the images on the homepage in the standard gallery method

Comment: Sure! Just use CSS. [This post should provide some guidance](http://theme.fm/2011/06/how-to-style-your-wordpress-gallery-43/).